# User specific information accessible everywhere. How to secure it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework. How can I secure my application so I cant access other users data?

To do CRUD stuff I have index, create, edit, delete methods in FooController so I can use:

```
/Foo/
```

to view my information I click one and get

```
/Foo/Details/5
```

When I type in 3 in the browser I get someone else's information.

```
/Foo/Details/3
```

How can I secure this from being accessed everywhere? I use Owin Identity and are logged into the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom authorization filter by deriving from the `AuthorizeAttribute` class and inside you could check whether the currently authenticated user has access to the requested resource.

For example:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string id = httpContext.Request["id"];
        string currentUser = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        return HasAccessToResource(id, currentUser);
    }

    private bool HasAccessToResource(string id, string currentUser)
    {
        // You know what to do here => check in your backend whether the 
        // current user is authorized to access the specified resource id
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then decorate your controllers/actions with this custom attribute:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public ActionResult Delete(string id)
{
    // if you get that far, the current user is owner of the requested resource
    ...    
}
```

Comment: This would give me filtering on the request only first? Similar to use [Authorize] attribute that a user is logged in? HasAccessToResource() is where I check that the the currentUser is allowed access on a specific row from "Foo Table"? 

What is preferred to link/check access rights on my AspNetUsers table and FooTable? FooId Foregin-Key in AspNetUsers table or AspNetUserId FK in FooTable?

Comment: The custom authorization attribute does all that the base Authorize attribute does (as it derives from it) but in addition it checks whether the currently authenticated user has access to certain resources. The way you would perform this check will greatly depend on your database design. But basically you need to store somewhere (in a table for example if you are using SQL) a mapping between users and resources. But that's an entirely different topic, it's unrelated to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Ok thanks alot Darin! Will try and find where I can learn more about that. Would you help and point me in the correct direction? It would be related to MVC, entity framework code first and tables on SQL. I have no idea what to search for to find an article on this topic.